# How do I match a string with "-" in it with LUA?

Tags: lua

I am trying to match text in between two strings. So far, this works well on 'find1', but 'find2' produces an error.

Example1:

```
find1 = cmd:match("<model>(.*)</model>") or "ERROR"
find2 = cmd:match("<sw-version>(.*)</sw-version>") or "ERROR"
print(find1, find2)
```

Result:

```
model
ERROR
```

Example2:

```
find1 = cmd:match("<model>(.*)</model>") or "ERROR"
find2 = cmd:match("<sw\-version>(.*)</sw\-version>") or "ERROR"
print(find1, find2)
```

Result:

```
model
ERROR
```

I am using and can only use native LUA. I believe my code is fine for the purpose I need. I am just wondering if "-" is an operator and/or if "-" is interpreting it as a range? If so, how do I fix it? I've tried it with the `"\"` escape character and it has not fixed it.

Comment: Just a warning: It seems like you're trying to read XML using Lua patterns. This works for simple cases where your data looks mostly the same, but breaks easily, so you may want to look into using a proper XML parsing library, depending on what you need this for.

Comment: Yes, It will always look exactly the same. I also am not directly using LUA. I'm using LUA through a separate application/service. So I cannot use any additions like xmlparse.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `%` symbol to escape special characters, (including `%` itself), so using `cmd:match("<sw%-version>(.*)</sw%-version>") or "ERROR"` should work. See the [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) for further details.

Comment: That works. You're a legend mate.

Comment: Another side question, if you will. Do you know how I could timeout this script in 10 seconds if there is no result by then? I see a few options but they all seem to complex for how simple I'm trying to keep this.

Comment: If the control is inside the `match` function, then there is not much you can do from the Lua level; if it's within some Lua code that you want to limit the overall execution time for, then you can probably use a debug hook with count or line execution and check the time spend to then abort the process (by returning `error` that you'll have to catch).